# Access django admin page behind Nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I am able to access all of my regular endpoints in my Django project, but I'm unable to access the /admin login page.
Whenever I try to enter the url/admin I get redirected to my top-url, the same happens in Postman.

I have the following Nginx file:

```
    location ~ /api {
            rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/backend.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/m3csadmin/backend;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the route to your admin login page? If you are using the `/admin/login`, there is no route in your nginx config that uses your wsgi. You are only sending `/api` traffic to your django app it looks like. What is your last `location /` intended for?

Comment: The admin login page is on the same place as the endpoints that actually work. for example, I can go to url/api/management and get a list from management. But if I go to url/api/admin I get redirected to url/ 

The location / is Angular, which hopefully shouldn't trigger as we hit /api  first?

Comment: Ok nice. Does it work locally, and just broken when using nginx? What are you settings and urls?

Comment: I think I have found the culprit. 
the Admin page of the Django framework does some redirects when you go to /admin, where one redirect seems to remove the /admin path from the url.

This means that nginx now picks up my "location /" which leads to an Angular page.

My solution was to break out the location /admin to another url, in this case we now use admin.company.com/admin instead of company.com/admin - One extra server tag in Nginx, but less headache.